# Add rows with same ID together after SELECT using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Hi all I am using LINQ to query a table like this:

```
AlbumID | Spotify | iTunes
--------------------------
   5    |   12    |   4
   5    |   18    |   6
   6    |   10    |   8
```

I would like to add together rows with the same unique `AlbumID`, I am aware of `GroupBy` but that groups together all similar IDs so I used `Where` that uses `albumID` (an input arg in this example it could be `5`)

```
var platformArray = Context.Analytics.Where(x => x.AlbumID == albumId).Select(s => new
{
    Id = s.AlbumID,
    Spotify = s.SpotifyClicks,
    Itunes = s.ItunesClicks
});
```

But when I print out to debug console, it does not combine the unique ID's

```
foreach (var item in platformArray)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(item.Id);
    Debug.WriteLine(item.Spotify);
    Debug.WriteLine(item.Itunes);
}
```

I see (added arrows for clarity):

```
5 <-ID
12 <-Spotify
4 <-ITunes
5 <-ID
18 <-Spotify
6 <-ITunes
```

How can I reformat my LINQ code to print out something like:

```
5 <-ID
30 <-Spotify
10 <-Itunes
```

Thanks!

EDIT: adding my Analytic Class

```
public class Analytic
{

    private object p1;
    private object p2;
    private object p3;

    public Analytic(object p1, object p2, object p3)
    {
        this.p1 = p1;
        this.p2 = p2;
        this.p3 = p3;
    }

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int AlbumID { get; set; }
    public int SpotifyClicks { get; set; }
    public int ItunesClicks { get; set; }

    public virtual Album Album { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried group by?

Comment: Just use `GroupBy` after `Where`

Comment: you can find it easily on this link: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e7ad0d7c-7bb5-4b13-b10f-8a77abd28844/lambda-expression-group-by-clause?forum=csharplanguage

Comment: @NiyokoYuliawan so I tried adding `GroupBy(x => x.AlbumID)` and my properties inside my Select (like s.AlbumID, s.Spotify) are underlined with error: IGrouping does not contain a definition for AlbumID and no extension method `AlbumID` accepting a first argument of type IGrouping could be found

Comment: @HasanGholamali your example counts the number of rows that are grouped together, this does not do what I wish to accomplish

Comment: @JordanLewallen did you try answer below?

Comment: just change count on the example to sum like the answer below

Comment: @HasanGholamali sorta working now, so the reason I was using `WHERE` in my initial question was because I don't want to query for items that are not an ID of 5. Now when I print out your suggested code, I get combined totals for both id's 5 AND 6 in my result. How do I only store the results of id = 5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to figure this out from the help of Hasan's comment on my original post and some additional fixes:

```
var query = Context.Analytics
.Where(x => x.AlbumID == albumId)
.GroupBy(c => c.AlbumID)
.Select(
    g =>
        new
        {
            Id = g.Key,
            Spotify = g.Sum(s => s.SpotifyClicks),
            ITunes = g.Sum(s => s.ItunesClicks),
        }
);
```

This only queries for my specific `albumID` and sums together all rows with that specific ID!

Thanks everyone

Comment: you're filtering based on album Id and selecting Id , why? if both Id and Album ID is same then why do you need two vars?

Comment: @Lucifer Id and AlbumID are different, Id is PK and AlbumID is FK'd to a specific album. I am tracking clicks per day, so every day a new row is added (I have a Date property in my full class that i removed for this example). Thus the Id will be incremented as a new row but AlbumID will stay the same

Comment: @Lucifer sort of...mostly Hassan's comment. I mean you can take my code answer and make it yours to credit you for your time if you'd like, I can mark that as correct :)

Comment: no I dont want credit :D I just asked if it helped you at all else I would delete it as not helpful answer :D  you can mark your own answer and up vote mine if helped.

Comment: @Lucifer oh gotcha! Haha sure let’s keep it up, I think someone may find it useful moving forward. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: For reasons that aren't clear to me, it is recommended you group by a constant when you have a single group (such as `GroupBy(c => 1)`).

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
var List =  from element in prod
            group element by new { element.Id } into g                
            select new yourClass
            (
                Id = g.First().ID,
                Spotify = g.Sum(s => s.Spotify)
                Itunes = g.Sum(s => s.Itunes)
            );
```

Comment: I'm trying this one out now, it's giving me a fuss about the `d` variable and the `yourClass` I switched it to my class `Analytic` but I don't have a constructor in my class definition

Comment: @JordanLewallen what do you mean by fuss?

Comment: so it's saying that 'd' does not exist in the current context, sorry for being so new at this, not quite sure what to put there!

Comment: alright progress, so that fixed the first error, now on to the next. the `yourClass` of which I replaced with `Analytic` which is the class I'm using here does not have a constructor I guess I would need to add? I posted my Analytic class to see what I am working with

Comment: @JordanLewallen add constructor

Comment: so I let VS auto generate a constructor for me, see my original question (added it there) is that correct? Because the Id, Spotify, Itunes on the left hand side of the = sign for each say "the name `` does not exist in the current context"

Answer (score 0):

So after you have grouped your Albums into groups of Albums with the same `AlbumId`, you want to transform all Albums in the group into one object, containing the common `AlbumId`, the total of all `Spotify` of all Albums in your group, and the total of all `iTunes` of all Albums in your group.

```
var result = albums.GroupBy(album => album.AlbumId)
    // from every group, make one element with the sum of Spotify and sum of itunes:
    .Select(group => new
    {
        AlbumId = group.Key,
        Spotify = group.Select(groupElement => groupElement.Spotify).Sum(),
        ITunes = group.Select(groupElement => groupElement.Itunes).Sum(),
    });
```

Simple comme bonjour!